# Create Alfresco Content Types using a UI

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am just starting out with Alfresco and am interested in creating content types that are specific to my business needs. From what I have read so far, I can do this by creating an XML file that defines a content type and then creating an AMP to customise Share to handle my new content type.

But Drupal, another CMS, allows you to create a content type using it's UI without having to write or deploy any code.

Is there a similar feature in Alfresco that will allow an admin to create a content type using a UI?

Answer (score 4):

There aren't a lot of options, but there is one addon:
[beCGP designer](https://www.becpg.fr/redmine/projects/designer)

I would also strongly suggest reading [Jeff Potts' tutorial on working with custom content types](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another interesting Alfresco Form & Model Management tool:
https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-form-model-management/